# Solving $(y+\sin x \cos^2(xy)-2x^2y)dx+(x+\sin y \cos^2(xy))dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

They ask you to solve the following differential equation, taking as data its integrating factor $u(x,y)$:

$$(y+\sin x \cos^2(xy)-2x^2y)dx+(x+\sin y \cos^2(xy))dy=0; \quad u(x,y)=u(xy)$$

This is my advance, then I could not conclude something else, since I could not simplify because of the integrating factor they ask for.

$Sol:$

As:

$N\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial x}-M\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$....(1)

$z=xy \rightarrow  (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=y \wedge  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x)$

$\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}.\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}.y$

$\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}.\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}.x$

Replacing in (1):

$N(\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}.y)-M(\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}x)=\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$

$\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}=\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{yN-xM}....(2)$

As:

$M=y+\sin(x)\cos^2(xy)-2x^2y$

$N=x+\sin(y)\cos^2(xy)$

$M_y=1-2x\sin(y)\cos(xy)\sin(xy)-2x^2$

$N_x=1-2y\sin(y)\cos(xy)\sin(xy)$

Replacing in (2):

$\frac{\partial Lnu}{\partial z}=\frac{1-2x\sin \left(x\right)\cos \left(xy\right)\sin \left(xy\right)-2x^2-\left(1-2y\sin \left(y\right)\cos \left(xy\right)\sin \left(xy\right)\right)}{\left[y\left(x+\sin \left(y\right)\cos ^2\left(xy\right)\right)-x\left(y+\sin \left(x\right)\cos ^2\left(xy\right)-2x^2y\right)\right]}$

I cannot simplify this last expression, or give it the form to replace xy = z

Comment: IS the differential equation correct ?

Comment: Yes, I also thought it was wrong, since it would come out immediately if in the equation for M the -2x ^ 2y were eliminated

Comment: Yes it causes some problem  or maybe a term is missing in N